# Windows Form "Hole"

Tags: c#, forms, graphics

How would I go about creating a dynamic "hole" in a windows form through which the user could see the actual desktop instead of the form? Right now I've created a translucent form on top of the entire screen and I'm looking to see through that translucent form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative if you need rectangular form of "hole" you can set form's `TransparencyKey` property to a certain color and then create a Panel with the background of the same color. (That panel will be transparent on run.)

Answer (score 12):

Use the form's [Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) property.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, this.Size);
Region region = new Region(rect);

rect.Inflate(-1 * (this.Width / 3), -1 * (this.Height / 3));
region.Exclude(rect);

this.Region = region;
```

That should put a hole through your form.

Comment: Excellent answer! Simple and nice!

Comment: Most splendid, sir! Thanks a lot!